# Anthology of short stories, one has a "Soylent Green" theme

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

Read a collection of sci-fi short stories in 2001-2002, so the book they were in is at least that old.

The first story I recall is a take on *Soylent Green*. In it, the elders of a village must at a certain age leave on a path away from the village to not return and live out their lives. The protagonist discovers that they aren't actually being allowed to leave but are being turned into food for the village.

The second story is about some kids exploring ruins and one of them discovers his father has been made into one of the stones composing the ruin and is able to talk to him.

Comment: Probably the book that is also searched for here: https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19210389-horror-scifi---collection-of-short-stories